# Emulating aspect-fit behaviour using AutoLayout constraints in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I want to use AutoLayout to size and layout a view in a manner that is reminiscent of UIImageView's aspect-fit content mode.

I have a subview inside a container view in Interface Builder. The subview has some inherent aspect ratio which I wish to respect. The container view's size is unknown until runtime.

If the container view's aspect ratio is wider than the subview, then I want the subview's height to equal the parent view's height.

If the container view's aspect ratio is taller than the subview, then I want the subview's width to equal the parent view's width.

In either case I wish the subview to be centered horizontally and vertically within the container view.

Is there a way to achieve this using AutoLayout constraints in Xcode 6 or in previous version? Ideally using Interface Builder, but if not perhaps it is possible to define such constraints programmatically.

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

You're not describing scale-to-fit; you're describing aspect-fit.  (I have edited your question in this regard.)  The subview becomes as large as possible while maintaining its aspect ratio and fitting entirely inside its parent.

Anyway, you can do this with auto layout.  You can do it entirely in IB as of Xcode 5.1.  Let's start with some views:

[image: some views]

The light green view has an aspect ratio of 4:1.  The dark green view has an aspect ratio of 1:4.  I'm going to set up constraints so that the blue view fills the top half of the screen, the pink view fills the bottom half of the screen, and each green view expands as much as possible while maintaining its aspect ratio and fitting in its container.

First, I'll create constraints on all four sides of the blue view.  I'll pin it to its nearest neighbor on each edge, with a distance of 0.  I make sure to turn off margins:

[image: blue constraints]

Note that I **don't** update the frame yet.  I find it easier to leave room between the views when setting up constraints, and just set the constants to 0 (or whatever) by hand.

Next, I pin the left, bottom, and right edges of the pink view to its nearest neighbor.  I don't need to set up a top edge constraint because its top edge is already constrained to the bottom edge of the blue view.

[image: pink constraints]

I also need an equal-heights constraint between the pink and blue views.  This will make them each fill half the screen:

[image]

If I tell Xcode to update all the frames now, I get this:

[image: containers laid out]

So the constraints I've set up so far are correct.  I undo that and start work on the light green view.

Aspect-fitting the light green view requires five constraints:

- A required-priority aspect ratio constraint on the light green view. You can create this constraint in a xib or storyboard with Xcode 5.1 or later.
- A required-priority constraint limiting the width of the light green view to be less than or equal to the width of its container.
- A high-priority constraint setting the width of the light green view to be equal to the width of its container.
- A required-priority constraint limiting the height of the light green view to be less than or equal to the height of its container.
- A high-priority constraint setting the height of the light green view to be equal to the height of its container.

Let's consider the two width constraints.  The less-than-or-equal constraint, by itself, is not sufficient to determine the width of the light green view; many widths will fit the constraint.  Since there's ambiguity, autolayout will try to choose a solution that minimizes the error in the other (high-priority but not required) constraint.  Minimizing the error means making the width as close as possible to the container's width, while not violating the required less-than-or-equal constraint.

The same thing happens with the height constraint.  And since the aspect-ratio constraint is also required, it can only maximize the size of the subview along one axis (unless the container happens to have the same aspect ratio as the subview).

So first I create the aspect ratio constraint:

[image: top aspect]

Then I create equal width and height constraints with the container:

[image: top equal size]

I need to edit these constraints to be less-than-or-equal constraints:

[image: top less than or equal size]

Next I need to create another set of equal width and height constraints with the container:

[image: top equal size again]

And I need to make these new constraints less than required priority:

[image: top equal not required]

Finally, you asked for the subview to be centered in its container, so I'll set up those constraints:

[image: top centered]

Now, to test, I'll select the view controller and ask Xcode to update all the frames.  This is what I get:

[image: incorrect top layout]

Oops!  The subview has expanded to completely fill its container.  If I select it, I can see that in fact it's maintained its aspect ratio, but it's doing an aspect-**fill** instead of an aspect-**fit**.

The problem is that on a less-than-or-equal constraint, it matters which view is at each end of the constraint, and Xcode has set up the constraint opposite from my expectation.  I could select each of the two constraints and reverse its first and second items.  Instead, I'll just select the subview and change the constraints to be greater-than-or-equal:

[image: fix top constraints]

Xcode updates the layout:

[image: correct top layout]

Now I do all the same things to the dark green view on the bottom.  I need to make sure its aspect ratio is 1:4 (Xcode resized it in a weird way since it didn't have constraints).  I won't show the steps again since they're the same.  Here's the result:

[image: correct top and bottom layout]

Now I can run it in the iPhone 4S simulator, which has a different screen size than IB used, and test rotation:

[image: iphone 4s test]

And I can test in in the iPhone 6 simulator:

[image: iphone 6 test]

I've uploaded my final storyboard to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/d9320088ab4025c95e40) for your convenience.

Comment: I wasn't even looking for any auto layout help, but followed the tweet. Now I've learned something. Well done. And you win!

Comment: What tool did you use to create the screencasts? And how did you get them into SO? Looks great.

Comment: I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).  It's free (GPL) and records directly to GIF.  As long as the animated GIF is no more than 2 MB, you can post it to this site like any other image.

Comment: Actually aspect ratio constraints are available in IB since Xcode 5.1, not from Xcode 6.0

Comment: @LucaTorella With only the high-priority constraints, the layout is ambiguous.  **Just because it gets your desired result today doesn't mean it will in the next version of iOS.**  Suppose the subview wants aspect ratio 1:1, the superview is size 99×100, and you only have the required aspect-ratio and high-priority equality constraints.  Then auto layout can set the subview to size 99×99 (with total error 1) or size 100×100 (with total error 1).  One size is aspect-fit; the other is aspect-fill.  Adding the required constraints produces a unique least-error solution.

Comment: @LucaTorella Thanks for the correction regarding the availability of aspect ratio constraints.

Comment: 10,000 better apps with just one post... incredible.

Comment: @robmayoff You sir, are an absolute legend!

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever seen on Stack Overflow and helps me enormously achieve something similar with autolayout. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is usefull but does have some limitations without explaining what the code is doing. For example, the example requires a parent container to work, if you're just using the superview, the UI in XCode is different. Likewise, there is no information on how to include padding around the aspect-ratio sized view. AutoLayout is one of the most complex things in iOS programmming. I don't know why it's so hard when we've been doing this kind of layout control in HTML/CSS for decades.

Comment: @simbolo Multiple questions warrant multiple answers.  I can't explain every detail of auto layout in a single answer.  If you need help with any of those things you mentioned in your comment, post new questions.

Comment: Really well explained, I am going to bookmark this answer and keep coming back until I am at peace with constraints :)

Comment: Wow.. Best answer here in stack overflow i've ever seen.. Thank you for this sir..

Comment: Can someone confirm, in history of StackOverflow, this answer seems to be the biggest (and the ultimate) answer? Awesome post @robmayoff, you put just too much efforts in answering :) **Edit:** it would be great, if he can count total Mbs occupied for this ;)

Comment: The most thorough answer in SO history.

Comment: In order for this to work with OSX apps, I needed to set the height/width priorities to 750/250 instead of 1000/750 - otherwise the window aspect ratio became fixed to have no 'blank' space around the content view. Which other property priority is this now defeating? Presumably a compression/hugging somewhere?

Comment: There is a list under “Aspect-fitting the light green view requires five constraints”. Create those five constraints in code.

Comment: For anyone looking to easily switch to **aspect fill**, instead of **>=** for the width and height constraints use **<=**

Answer (score 24):

Rob, your answer is awesome!
I also know that this question is specifically about achieving this by using auto-layout. However, just as a reference, I'd like to show how this can be done in code. You set up the top and bottom views (blue and pink) just like Rob showed. Then you create a custom `AspectFitView`:

**AspectFitView.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AspectFitView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *childView;

@end
```

**AspectFitView.m**:

```
#import "AspectFitView.h"

@implementation AspectFitView

- (void)setChildView:(UIView *)childView
{
    if (_childView) {
        [_childView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    _childView = childView;

    [self addSubview:childView];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (_childView) {
        CGSize childSize = _childView.frame.size;
        CGSize parentSize = self.frame.size;
        CGFloat aspectRatioForHeight = childSize.width / childSize.height;
        CGFloat aspectRatioForWidth = childSize.height / childSize.width;

        if ((parentSize.height * aspectRatioForHeight) > parentSize.height) {
            // whole height, adjust width
            CGFloat width = parentSize.width * aspectRatioForWidth;
            _childView.frame = CGRectMake((parentSize.width - width) / 2.0, 0, width, parentSize.height);
        } else {
            // whole width, adjust height
            CGFloat height = parentSize.height * aspectRatioForHeight;
            _childView.frame = CGRectMake(0, (parentSize.height - height) / 2.0, parentSize.width, height);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Next, you change the class of the blue and pink views in the storyboard to be `AspectFitView`s. Finally you set two outlets to your viewcontroller `topAspectFitView` and `bottomAspectFitView` and set their `childView`s in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *top = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 100)];
    top.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 500)];
    bottom.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    _topAspectFitView.childView = top;
    _bottomAspectFitView.childView = bottom;
}
```

So it's not hard to do this in code and it is still very adaptable and works with variably-sized views and different aspect ratios.

**Update July 2015**: Find a demo app here: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/SPWKAspectFitView

Comment: Very helpful to have the programmatic reference as well.

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug if you have tutorial project , can you share ? thank you :)

Comment: @ErhanDemirci Sure, here you go: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/SPWKAspectFitView

Answer (score 15):

**This is for macOS.**

I have problem to use Rob's way to achieve aspect fit on the OS X application. But I made it with another way -- Instead of using width and height, I used leading, trailing, top and bottom space.

Basically, add two leading spaces where one is >= 0 @1000 required priority and another one is = 0 @250 low priority. Do same settings to trailing, top and bottom space.

Of course, you need to set aspect ratio and centre X and centre Y.

And then job's done!

[image]
[image]

Comment: How might you go about doing this programmatically?

Comment: @FateNuller Just following the steps?

Comment: For simplicity and straightforward THIS actually should be accepted answer. Works for iOS as well.

Comment: this is working in iOS as well, this should be accepted answer :)

Answer (score 10):

I needed a solution from the accepted answer, but executed from the code. The most elegant way I've found is using [Masonry framework](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry).

```
#import "Masonry.h"

...

[view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.width.equalTo(view.mas_height).multipliedBy(aspectRatio);
    make.size.lessThanOrEqualTo(superview);
    make.size.equalTo(superview).with.priorityHigh();
    make.center.equalTo(superview);
}];
```

Comment: thanx man, this was perfect and so easy, also less code :)

Answer (score 5):

I found myself wanting aspect-**fill** behavior so that a UIImageView would maintain its own aspect ratio and entirely fill the container view. Confusingly, my UIImageView was breaking BOTH high-priority equal-width and equal-height constraints (described in Rob's answer) and rendering at full resolution.

The solution was simply to set the UIImageView's Content Compression Resistance Priority lower than the priority of the equal-width and equal-height constraints:

[image: Content Compression Resistance]

Answer (score 2):

This is a port of @rob_mayoff's excellent answer to a code-centric approach, using `NSLayoutAnchor` objects and ported to Xamarin. For me, `NSLayoutAnchor` and related classes have made AutoLayout much easier to program:

```
public class ContentView : UIView
{
        public ContentView (UIColor fillColor)
        {
            BackgroundColor = fillColor;
        }
}

public class MyController : UIViewController 
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        //Starting point:
        var view = new ContentView (UIColor.White);

        blueView = new ContentView (UIColor.FromRGB (166, 200, 255));
        view.AddSubview (blueView);

        lightGreenView = new ContentView (UIColor.FromRGB (200, 255, 220));
        lightGreenView.Frame = new CGRect (20, 40, 200, 60);

        view.AddSubview (lightGreenView);

        pinkView = new ContentView (UIColor.FromRGB (255, 204, 240));
        view.AddSubview (pinkView);

        greenView = new ContentView (UIColor.Green);
        greenView.Frame = new CGRect (80, 20, 40, 200);
        pinkView.AddSubview (greenView);

        //Now start doing in code the things that @rob_mayoff did in IB

        //Make the blue view size up to its parent, but half the height
        blueView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        var blueConstraints = new []
        {
            blueView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.LayoutMarginsGuide.LeadingAnchor),
            blueView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor),
            blueView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.LayoutMarginsGuide.TopAnchor),
            blueView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.LayoutMarginsGuide.HeightAnchor, (nfloat) 0.5)
        };
        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (blueConstraints);

        //Make the pink view same size as blue view, and linked to bottom of blue view
        pinkView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        var pinkConstraints = new []
        {
            pinkView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.LeadingAnchor),
            pinkView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.TrailingAnchor),
            pinkView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.HeightAnchor),
            pinkView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.BottomAnchor)
        };
        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (pinkConstraints);


        //From here, address the aspect-fitting challenge:

        lightGreenView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        //These are the must-fulfill constraints: 
        var lightGreenConstraints = new []
        {
            //Aspect ratio of 1 : 5
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(lightGreenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lightGreenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, (nfloat) 0.20, 0),
            //Cannot be larger than parent's width or height
            lightGreenView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintLessThanOrEqualTo(blueView.WidthAnchor),
            lightGreenView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintLessThanOrEqualTo(blueView.HeightAnchor),
            //Center in parent
            lightGreenView.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.CenterYAnchor),
            lightGreenView.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.CenterXAnchor)
        };
        //Must-fulfill
        foreach (var c in lightGreenConstraints) 
        {
            c.Priority = 1000;
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (lightGreenConstraints);

        //Low priority constraint to attempt to fill parent as much as possible (but lower priority than previous)
        var lightGreenLowPriorityConstraints = new []
         {
            lightGreenView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.WidthAnchor),
            lightGreenView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(blueView.HeightAnchor)
        };
        //Lower priority
        foreach (var c in lightGreenLowPriorityConstraints) 
        {
            c.Priority = 750;
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (lightGreenLowPriorityConstraints);

        //Aspect-fit on the green view now
        greenView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        var greenConstraints = new []
        {
            //Aspect ratio of 5:1
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, greenView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, (nfloat) 5.0, 0),
            //Cannot be larger than parent's width or height
            greenView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintLessThanOrEqualTo(pinkView.WidthAnchor),
            greenView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintLessThanOrEqualTo(pinkView.HeightAnchor),
            //Center in parent
            greenView.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(pinkView.CenterXAnchor),
            greenView.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(pinkView.CenterYAnchor)
        };
        //Must fulfill
        foreach (var c in greenConstraints) 
        {
            c.Priority = 1000;
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (greenConstraints);

        //Low priority constraint to attempt to fill parent as much as possible (but lower priority than previous)
        var greenLowPriorityConstraints = new []
        {
            greenView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(pinkView.WidthAnchor),
            greenView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(pinkView.HeightAnchor)
        };
        //Lower-priority than above
        foreach (var c in greenLowPriorityConstraints) 
        {
            c.Priority = 750;
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints (greenLowPriorityConstraints);

        this.View = view;

        view.LayoutIfNeeded ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the shortest answer, with [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/), which also supports aspect-fill and stretch.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ContentMode) {
    ContentMode_aspectFit,
    ContentMode_aspectFill,
    ContentMode_stretch
}

// ....

[containerView addSubview:subview];

[subview mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    if (contentMode == ContentMode_stretch) {
        make.edges.equalTo(containerView);
    }
    else {
        make.center.equalTo(containerView);
        make.edges.equalTo(containerView).priorityHigh();
        make.width.equalTo(content.mas_height).multipliedBy(4.0 / 3); // the aspect ratio
        if (contentMode == ContentMode_aspectFit) {
            make.width.height.lessThanOrEqualTo(containerView);
        }
        else { // contentMode == ContentMode_aspectFill
            make.width.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(containerView);
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any ready-to-go fully programatical solution, so here is my take in **swift 5** for the **aspect fill** extension to a view:

```swift
extension UIView {

    public enum FillingMode {
        case full(padding:Int = 0)
        case aspectFit(ratio:CGFloat)
        // case aspectFill ...
    }

    public func addSubview(_ newView:UIView, withFillingMode fillingMode:FillingMode) {
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(newView)

        switch fillingMode {
        case let .full(padding):
            let cgPadding = CGFloat(padding)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: cgPadding),
                newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -cgPadding),
                newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: cgPadding),
                newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -cgPadding)
            ])
        case let .aspectFit(ratio):
            guard ratio != 0 else { return }

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

                newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: leadingAnchor),
                newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).usingPriority(900),

                newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: trailingAnchor),
                newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).usingPriority(900),

                newView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor),
                newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).usingPriority(900),

                newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor),
                newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).usingPriority(900),

                newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.widthAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(ratio)),
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the priority extension (comes from another thread but I "secured it" with some pattern matching between 1...1000:

```swift
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    /// Returns the constraint sender with the passed priority.
    ///
    /// - Parameter priority: The priority to be set.
    /// - Returns: The sended constraint adjusted with the new priority.
    func usingPriority(_ priority: Int) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        self.priority = UILayoutPriority( (1...1000 ~= priority) ? Float(priority) : 1000 )
        return self
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ~