# iOS Autolayout to set width and height according to screen size

Tags: autolayout, ios-autolayout

What constraints I should add to set width and height proportional to the Superview (in my case its the UIViewController's view) in iOS Autolayout, with Autoresizing we can do like the pic shown below.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about aspect fit, [and is this a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766747/emulating-aspect-fit-behaviour-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-6)?

Answer (score 4):

if a uiview in a uiviewcontroller.

1. you must add centre horizontally and vertically in container constraint for that uiview.
2. you need to add equal height and equal width constraint for that uiview with your super view.
3. select both equal height constraint and equal width constraint and add multiplier to that constraint as your needs.

Comment: Question is, how to calculate multiplier. E.g on 480(iphone 4) i want view  height to be 40 in iPhone 5s , thats 18.33% increase so i will set multiplier to increase 40 + 40*18.33% , however the increase in iPhone 6/6plus is different. So how can i set one multiplier for all