# How to handle different fonts & image sizes for different device resolutions?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, size-classes

I'm working on an iPhone only app supports from **iOS 8**. I want to support devices from **iPhone 4S** in a portrait mode only.

I have a graphic design which is taking a fullscreen content. I'm using auto-layout to handle the views and making it work for all screens. **But, I'm using a small assets to manage the design to work from iPhone 4S.** When I see it in iPhone 6S/6, contents are very small and lot of extra spaces are getting wasted.

**I want to increase the font size, image sizes when a device resolution is getting bigger.** There are many screens in this app.

> For e.g., I've a label with font size 10pt in iPhone 4S screen. Even
>   after scaling, I see that font size is small in iPhone 6/6S. I'd like
>   to increase the font size to 13pt or higher.

How to handle that? Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I'm supporting only for iPhone in a portrait mode. When we do that, all screens are having size classes with Regular Height & Compact Width. So, storyboard setting for different fonts will not have any change in the actual screens.

Comment: Provide the files in several sizes with the `@2x` and `@3x` naming convention. There should be no need to change the font sizes at all.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I want to have different font sizes for each devices. Even after scaling, I see the fonts are small and can be increased. But If I increase in storyboard, I'll leave the 4S screen congested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for other fellows.

Earlier, I wasn't aware of `'Minimum Font Scale'` & `'Aspect Ratio'` options in Autolayout.

After some researching, I could accomplish resizing of views and font sizes with them. Here are the few answers which helped me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909109/1083859

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853203/1083859

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768875/1083859

Answer (score 0):

To manage Images for all devices add images to Images.xcassets folder for all devices by adding 1x, 2x and 3x images.

[image]

To display font according to size of device you can use size classes for different devices.

Tap small plus button in front of Font in Attribute Inspector and maintain size for different devices.

[image]

Comment: I'm supporting only for iPhone in a portrait mode. When we do that, all screens are having size classes with Regular Height & Compact Width. So storyboard setting for different fonts will not have any change in the actual screens.