# How to set aspect ration between two different UIViews instead of sides on one UIView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a yellow `UIView` and a blue `UIView`. The height of yellow one is dynamic and changes. The height of a blue one is always two times smaller than the yellow one. How to set constraints to achieve this? Is it possible at all?

Basically:

How to set aspect ratio between any of two `UIView`s?

Comment: Provide screen you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

Of course it is! You should set the constraint to `Equal Heights` between these two views and then change it's multiplier to `1:2` or `2:1` depending on which of the views is "first". In order to add a constraint control-drag from one view to the other.

[image: constraint]

Comment: Pretty awesome answer, thanks:)

Comment: No problem. In future, please search first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742897/autolayout-aspect-ratio-for-uiimageview-uiview . I didn't check at first, as it was faster to write the answer than to check for duplicates, though I'm marking the question as one ;]

Answer (score 1):

Make reference of height constraints  of both the view. 
When you change height of the yellow UIView to some dynamic value x , change the hight constraints of the blue UIView to  x/2 .

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Set height constraint of AView and make outlet of the constraint.
2. Set EqualHeight of BView To AView.
3. Set EqualHeight constraints multiplier as 1:2.
4. Update height constraint as you want.

   ```
   @IBAction func buttonToggleAViewHeightClicked(sender: UIButton) {

   if sender.selected {
       constraintHeightAView.constant = constraintHeightAView.constant - 200
       sender.selected = false
   } else {
       constraintHeightAView.constant = constraintHeightAView.constant + 200
       sender.selected = true
   }

       UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }

   }
   ```