# Custom specific Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I have a design for app where Tabbar looks like this:

[image: design of Toolbar]

I tried to add TabBarController and change its background but TabBar's background has only original size of image that looks bad on different iPhone models.

The next idea was to add a View on the bottom MainView and add UIImageView in bottom View. It looks nice but only on iPhone 7/8. On another models it looks bad because they have different width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aspect ratio for handling different device resolution for tabbar view. So it will create tabbar with different height and width for each device as per its size.

You can refer below links for aspect ratio:

[Autolayout aspect ratio for UIImageView / UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742897/autolayout-aspect-ratio-for-uiimageview-uiview)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try it. Can u help me with another question? Its normal that I add 2 Buttons and switch View on click them?

Comment: Do you need to change image of tab on click of tab button?? If you want to change the image then you can directly set selected image for button and manage using selected state of button