# how to use aspect ratio between subview and super view in xib files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

I am using Auto layout in xib files and not using `Storyboard`.
I have added one `UIImageView` on self.view. I am trying to set the aspect ratio on `UIImageView` width and super view height. But when I drag the control from `UIImageView`( subview) to self.view (superview) to enable the aspect ratio option but I am surprised that aspect ratio option is not coming.

Only four option are coming

1. Trailing space to container.
2. Top space to container.
3. Centre Horizontally in container  .
4. Centre vertically in container.

How to set the aspect ratio between *subview* and *superview*.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Aspect ratio between two views doesn't really make that much sense. Are you sure you don't mean proportional width or height?

Comment: yes i mean the same and i am able to do the same in storyboard.but unable to do without storyboard.

Comment: The pin option has a aspect ratio setting even in xib. For setting aspect ration, select both the view elements and then set aspect ratio.

Comment: i did the same but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emulating aspect-fit behaviour using AutoLayout constraints in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766747/emulating-aspect-fit-behaviour-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-6)

Excellent and simple explanation (with images!) that just might help you solve the problem. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why XIBs don't allow you to set Aspect Ratio constraints at the top level. Here is a workaround:

1. Add a view to the top level view.
2. Pin its top, left, right, and bottom to the top level view's top, left, right, and bottom. Make all offsets 0.
3. Now you can add your imageView to this view and use an Aspect Ratio constraint as you would expect.