# I cannot find the align and pin buttons in xcode6.4 to adjust constraints for aspect fit

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, constraints

I am now using xcode6.4

In this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768875/80353
you can clearly see the options for align, pin, etc to set the constraints.

However, after selecting a label element, I am unable to trigger the same.

In fact, I now have the following instead.

[image]

So how do I adjust constraints such as width constraints for the label and constraints away from left most edge and top most edge?

Comment: Did you checked `Use Auto Layout` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have checked the option to `Use Auto Layout`. Refer the image below
[image]

Under Utilities > File Inspector

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this option?

Comment: I found it. It's under utilities view > File Inspector. Thank you.