# Set subview height relative to parent view in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a `UIImageView` in a `UIViewController's` view. What I want is to set it's height **1/3rd** that of the view no matter what the screen size is. I of course know how to do this from code. But how to accomplish this using **Storyboard/Interface builder** only ?

Comment: You can easily do that with auto layout. Add an height constraint to image view with some aspect ratio.

Comment: @ozgur : But if I set the4 height constraint, it's height would be always same for all devices. Won't it ?

Comment: No. This is why I mentioned about *aspect ratio*. You are setting height with respect to its superview's height. So it will grow as the superview grows. Please take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766747/emulating-aspect-fit-behaviour-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-6).

Comment: @ozgur : Many thanks. Feel sorry for myself that didn't know about this constraint. Quite useful.You might wanna add an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a height constraint whose *multiplier* value is `1/3` so the image view's height will be one third of its superview's height.

[image]

--

Here is how it looks with different device sizes:

[image: Bad rendering on small screen]    [image: Bad rendering on small screen]     [image: Bad rendering on small screen]

Comment: Thanks for the illustration. Appreciate !!